Project Reference 'System.Web.Http' Error
When I try to regenerate my project, I have the Error :

Error CS1705 Assembly 'Exp2.Service.API' with identity
'SAM2.Service.API, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.3.0.0 ,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' whose version is
greater than that of the assembly referenced 'System.Web.Http' with
the identity 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.9.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

The version of System.Web.Http.dll for the project Exp2.Service.API is : 5.3.61130.
Exp2.Service.API is a sub-project referenced in the main project Ws_Temp.
The version of System.Web.Http.dll for the project Ws_Temp is : 5.2.9-61139.
And Ws_Temp\Web.config contains :
 <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.9.0" newVersion="5.2.9.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>

Could you help me, please ?
Thank you in advance.
Eric.

Finally, I managed to clean the references and it works now.
